# CSS not being applied to ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

To add im using jquery mobile.

So Im using ASP.Net MVC, and sticking the CSS, jquery etc in the the layout page.
So on initial load the page looks fine

[image]

Then when the date changes I call the ajacx to return a partial view this happens

[image]

**So whats the solution?**

Layout Page

```
@{
    Layout = null;

}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker/jquery.ui.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="../../Content/CheckBoxToggle/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       <script src="~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery.1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/JQuery/Mobile/jquerymobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/JQuery/UI/jqueryUI-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        @RenderBody();
  </body>

</html>
```

View

```
@model WebUI.ViewModels.ScheduleMobileDisplay
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AppHomeLayout.Iphone.cshtml";

}



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div data-role="page" id="pageAccount">
        <link href="~/Content/CSS/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker(
                    {
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                            var date = $(this).val();
                            UpdateSchedule(date);
                        }
                    });
            });
            function UpdateSchedule(date) {
                var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("GetMobileScheduleResults")';


                 $.ajax({
                     url: baseUrl,
                     type: 'GET',
                     data: { date: date }
                 }).done(function (response) {
                     $('#schedule').html(response);
                 });
             }
        </script>
        @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_MobileMenu.Iphone.cshtml")
        <div data-role="content">

            <input type="text" id="datepicker"  placeholder="Select Date" />
            <div id="schedule">
              @{ Html.RenderPartial("MobileScheduleList", Model); }
            </div>


        </div>

    </div>

}
```

Partial View

```
@model WebUI.ViewModels.ScheduleMobileDisplay
        <script src="~/Scripts/JQuery/Mobile/jquerymobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                    @Model.AppointmentDate
                </li>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Appointments)
                {
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="/Schedule/MobileAppointmentEdit/@item.Id" data-transition="slide">
                            @item.StartTime @item.PetName
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }

            </ul>
```

UPDATE://

Tried this but does not work

```
$.ajax({
                     url: baseUrl,
                     type: 'GET',
                     data: { date: date },
                     success: function (response) {
                         alert('hi1');
                         $('#schedule').html(response);
                     },
                     complete:function() {
                         alert('comp');

                         $('#lst').listview('refresh');
                     },

                 });
```

Comment: You didn't read documentation, this is covered there.. After you add new markup you need to refresh it in order to initialize list view again on new items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to do this

```
success: function (response) {
   $('#schedule').html(response);
   $("#schedule ul").listview();
},
```

Answer (score 5):

In the ajax OnComplete method, call the code below to apply the styling

```
$('#listId').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: Sorry, do you mean add it here?  $.ajax({
                     url: baseUrl,
                     type: 'GET',
                     data: { date: date }
                 }).done(function (response) {
                     $('#schedule').html(response);
                 });

Comment: You'll want to run it after you add the html, but you need the id of the list. Add an id to your ul in your partial and reference it for the list view refresh (<ul id="listId" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">)

Comment: So i added the id <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true" id="listId"> and then added $.ajax({
                     url: baseUrl,
                     type: 'GET',
                     data: { date: date },
                     success: function (response) {
                         $('#schedule').html(response);
                     },
                     complete:function() {  $('#listId').listview('refresh');
                     },
                    
                 }); still no luck :(